# Clarification on why question was migrated

Tags: support, specific-question

Can I get clarification on why question was migrated?

https://superuser.com/questions/797205/setup-php-from-source-and-mod-fgcid-on-centos-6-getting-permission-denied

Seems very specifically a SF type question to me.

Comment: While Server Fault is about Servers, Networks, and related deployments - they are very specifically geared towards *professional* sysadmin tasks and problems. Your problem sounds like a generic php setup problem. Are you doing this in a corporate environment? If not then that would be why it got migrated here. If so then mentioning might have helped, but it would probably still have been migrated.

Comment: @Mokubai it most definitely is in a corporate environment, and I am a *professional* sysadmin. I primarily work on Debian, whereas the corporate entity in question is 100% CentOS based. It is for a  internet layer 2 provisioning application. It just seems presumptuous to assume it was not.

Comment: In that case I am at a bit of a loss as to why. It may be worth asking this on meta.SF

Comment: @Mokubai's right, SU's just the passive recipient of the question -- the decision happened on SF.

Comment: I was not involved in this, and I saw this question and decided _not_ to close it, but I would guess that it had something to do with an apparent unexplained disregard for best practices (which wasn't [explained](http://superuser.com/questions/797205/setup-php-from-source-and-mod-fgcid-on-centos-6-getting-permission-denied#comment1040825_797205) until _after_ the question was migrated).

Answer (score 2):

I meant to answer your question in chat the other day but I got busy and forgot.

To me your question looked no different to any number of similar questions we get from developers about their environments all the time. Rather than installing from a package (which is available) a choice was made to install from source, this is nearly always against best practice and leads to problems (as you found).

You mentioned that you were using CentOS but didn't mention which version (there are currently 3 supported releases) I would expect someone within our target community to know that the version was important and provide the relevant information.

Your question looked like it was from someone outside our target audience so I voted to close it and send it to Super User which is a better place for such questions.

By the way your solution is at best temporary, a restorecon will undo the chcon, you should look to semanage for a permanent fix.

Comment: Offtopic to this meta question, but does `restorecon` get called automatically, or does it require manual execution?